# mdatp_audisp_pl is consuming a lot of CPU

Tags: plugins, cpu, azure-defender

Microsoft defender audit plugin (mdatp_audisp_pl) is consuming excessively CPU resources (up to 40-50%) on a few Centos VMs on Azure

Does a restart of this audit plugin harmless and can help ?
Do you have any tips or solution ?

Thank you in advance

Cyril